# How to add view in custom layout in runtime

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I am creating custom layout (extends FrameLayout). I have a bunch of view defined in xml(it doesn't matter now).
What I need to do. My custom layout has custom defined attributes, let's assume that it named `footer_banner_type`.
I have different Banners classes some of them I quite different from one another, so I cannot place some base banner in xml. So I have to add some banner based on attribute value.
I am extending `FrameLayout` . I am newbie and this is my first custom layout.

I don't know how to improve performance.
As I understand Layout iterating and inflating all child views. But if I need to add view in runtime.I don't want to make layout reiterate view hierarchy, because it will be performance issue.
My question is how to implement my task in better way.

Answer (score 1):

```
//First create your view:
View wonderfulView = new View(this.getApplicationContext());
//Then, create its LayoutParams
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1);
//Set those layout params in your view
wonderfulView.setLayoutParams(params);
//finaly, add the view to your ViewGroup
yourLayout.addView(wonderfulView);
```

That's it.

If you want to change the view container, you'll have to remove it form the previous parent like this:

```
View movingThing = ((YourLayoutClass)findViewById(R.id.currentContainer)).getChildAt(WhereYourViewis);
((YourLayoutClass)findViewById(R.id.currentContainer)).removeView(movingThing);
((YourLayoutClass)findViewById(R.id.newContainer)).addView(movingThing);
```